# Snowflake XML parse if element doesn't exists

Tags: xml, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lateral

I wrote the following XML query to parse the XML file into my Snowflake database:

```
   SELECT XMLGET( prodCstmsHdr.value, 'prodCd' )
FROM (SELECT XMLDOC
          FROM RAW.WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS
       WHERE WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID = 
                (SELECT MAX(WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID) 
                    FROM RAW.WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS
                    WHERE WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID = 1623
                )
        ) btt
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(btt.xmldoc:"$") body
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(body.VALUE:"$") prodCstmsHdr
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodCstmsHdr.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnDtl
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnDtl.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnItm
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnItm.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnHTSGrp
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnItm.VALUE:"$") prodMatlCntnt
WHERE 1=1
  AND GET(prodCstmsHdr.value, '@') = 'prodCstmsHdr'
  AND GET(prodClsfnDtl.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnDtl'
  AND GET(prodClsfnItm.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnItm'
  AND GET(prodClsfnHTSGrp.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnHTSGrp'
  **AND GET(prodMatlCntnt.value, '@') = 'prodMatlCntnt'**
  AND XMLGET( prodCstmsHdr.value, 'prodCd' ):"$"::STRING IN ( '169831A', '5700123')
```

with the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getProductClassificationUpdatesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.int.XXXXX.com/customs/globalproductdetails/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://customs.XXXX.com/webservice/soapfault">
                <prodCstmsHdr>
                    <brand>Brand 1</brand>
                    <company>company name</company>
                    <divNm>20</divNm>
                    <divisionDescription>FOOTWEAR</divisionDescription>
                    <gndrAgeDesc>ADULT UNISEX</gndrAgeDesc>
                    <gndrAgeNm>01</gndrAgeNm>
                    <prodCd>169831A</prodCd>
                    <prodClsfnDtl>
                        <cmpndTypeNm>IND</cmpndTypeNm>
                        <imprtCtryCd>EU</imprtCtryCd>
                        <prodClsfnItm>
                            <lastUpdatedDate>2020-05-13T12:15:32.102-07:00</lastUpdatedDate>
                            <primFlag>Y</primFlag>
                            <prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                                <fromPrc>0</fromPrc>
                                <fromSz>0C</fromSz>
                                <hts>64039111111</hts>
                                <prcDirection>UP</prcDirection>
                                <szDirection>ABOVE</szDirection>
                            </prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                            <valPctg>100</valPctg>
                            <valTypeNm>BY PERCENTAGE</valTypeNm>
                        </prodClsfnItm>
                        <prodTypeNm>Inline</prodTypeNm>
                    </prodClsfnDtl>
                    <prodPoDtl>
                        <originCountries>US</originCountries>
                        <uom>PR</uom>
                    </prodPoDtl>
                    <seasonNm>Season 2020</seasonNm>
                    <silDesc>Sil description</silDesc>
                    <silNm>020</silNm>
                    <sportActyDesc>Football</sportActyDesc>
                    <sportActyNm>04</sportActyNm>
                </prodCstmsHdr>
                <prodCstmsHdr>
                    <brand>Brand 1</brand>
                    <company>Company name</company>
                    <divNm>20</divNm>
                    <divisionDescription>FOOTWEAR</divisionDescription>
                    <gndrAgeDesc>WOMENS</gndrAgeDesc>
                    <gndrAgeNm>22</gndrAgeNm>
                    <prodCd>5700123</prodCd>
                    <prodClsfnDtl>
                        <cmpndTypeNm>INDIVIDUAL</cmpndTypeNm>
                        <imprtCtryCd>EU</imprtCtryCd>
                        <prodClsfnItm>
                            <itmTypeNm>SHOE</itmTypeNm>
                            <lastUpdatedDate>2020-05-07T12:03:38.933-07:00</lastUpdatedDate>
                            <primFlag>Y</primFlag>
                            <prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                                <fromPrc>0</fromPrc>
                                <fromSz>0C</fromSz>
                                <hts>64041111000</hts>
                                <htsDesc>OTHER</htsDesc>
                                <prcDirection>UP</prcDirection>
                                <szDirection>ABOVE</szDirection>
                            </prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                            <prodMatlCntnt>
                                <athleticFootwear>N</athleticFootwear>
                                <constrCharacteristicDesc>Lined</constrCharacteristicDesc>
                                <constrProcessDesc>V</constrProcessDesc>
                                <coversAnkle>Y</coversAnkle>
                                <factoryCode>9K</factoryCode>
                                <fastenerTypeDesc>Lacing</fastenerTypeDesc>
                                <heelStrapFlag>N</heelStrapFlag>
                                <liningPrimary>
                                    <fiber1>Cotton</fiber1>
                                    <fiber1Percent>100</fiber1Percent>
                                    <material>Textile</material>
                                </liningPrimary>
                                <liningSecondary>
                                    <fiber1>Synthetic Leather</fiber1>
                                    <material>Synthetic</material>
                                </liningSecondary>
                                <measurementSummary>
                                    <coatedLeatherPct>0.0</coatedLeatherPct>
                                    <leatherPct>0.0</leatherPct>
                                    <otherPct>0.0</otherPct>
                                    <summMethodCd>A</summMethodCd>
                                    <syntheticPct>0.0</syntheticPct>
                                    <textilePct>100.0</textilePct>
                                </measurementSummary>
                                <midsole>
                                    <primaryMaterial>EVA</primaryMaterial>
                                </midsole>
                                <onePieceFtw>N</onePieceFtw>
                                <onePieceSole>N</onePieceSole>
                                <openHeelFlag>N</openHeelFlag>
                                <openToeFlag>N</openToeFlag>
                                <outsole>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Rubber</primaryMaterial>
                                    <primaryMaterialPercent>100</primaryMaterialPercent>
                                </outsole>
                                <plugsBottom>N</plugsBottom>
                                <plugsSide>N</plugsSide>
                                <primTechFeatureDesc>Low Density Polymer</primTechFeatureDesc>
                                <sockliner>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Textile</primaryMaterial>
                                </sockliner>
                                <uprLthrNm/>
                                <uprMajority>Textile</uprMajority>
                                <uprOther/>
                                <uprSynthetic/>
                                <uprTextile>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Polyester</primaryMaterial>
                                    <primaryMaterialPercent>100</primaryMaterialPercent>
                                </uprTextile>
                            </prodMatlCntnt>
                            <valPctg>100</valPctg>
                            <valTypeNm>BY PERCENTAGE</valTypeNm>
                        </prodClsfnItm>
                        <prodTypeNm>Inline</prodTypeNm>
                    </prodClsfnDtl>
                    <prodPoDtl>
                        <originCountries>VN</originCountries>
                        <uom>PR</uom>
                    </prodPoDtl>
                    <seasonNm>Season 2020</seasonNm>
                    <silDesc>Sil description</silDesc>
                    <silNm>020</silNm>
                    <sportActyDesc>CASUAL/LEISURE</sportActyDesc>
                    <sportActyNm>29</sportActyNm>
                </prodCstmsHdr>
        </ns2:getProductClassificationUpdatesResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Because product 169831A is missing the node "prodMatlCntnt" the data won't show up.
Removing the condition "AND GET(prodMatlCntnt.value, '@') = 'prodMatlCntnt'" will cause duplicates. This is normally not an issue but I have more nodes in my file as you can see and the query takes forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem as described is to avoid doing all the inner joins that create all the duplicates.

In the problem as presented there's no need to do look at the inner values. Please rephrase the problem if any of those values are really required.

Solution:

```sql
SELECT XMLGET( prodCstmsHdr.value, 'prodCd' )
FROM (SELECT XMLDOC
          FROM xml
       -- WHERE WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID = 
       --          (SELECT MAX(WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID) 
       --              FROM RAW.WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS
       --              WHERE WE_BREXIT_TRADE_TERMS_UID = 1623
       --          )
        ) btt
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(btt.xmldoc:"$") body
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(body.VALUE:"$") prodCstmsHdr
    -- INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodCstmsHdr.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnDtl
    -- INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnDtl.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnItm
    -- INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnItm.VALUE:"$") prodClsfnHTSGrp
    -- LEFT JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(prodClsfnItm.VALUE:"$") prodMatlCntnt
WHERE 1=1
  -- AND GET(prodCstmsHdr.value, '@') = 'prodCstmsHdr'
  -- AND GET(prodClsfnDtl.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnDtl'
  -- AND GET(prodClsfnItm.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnItm'
  -- AND GET(prodClsfnHTSGrp.value, '@') = 'prodClsfnHTSGrp'
  --
  -- AND GET(prodMatlCntnt.value, '@') = 'prodMatlCntnt'
  --
AND XMLGET( prodCstmsHdr.value, 'prodCd' ):"$"::STRING IN ( '169831A', '5700123')
```

[image]

Staging:

```sql
create or replace temp table xml as
select PARSE_XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getProductClassificationUpdatesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.int.XXXXX.com/customs/globalproductdetails/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://customs.XXXX.com/webservice/soapfault">
                <prodCstmsHdr>
                    <brand>Brand 1</brand>
                    <company>company name</company>
                    <divNm>20</divNm>
                    <divisionDescription>FOOTWEAR</divisionDescription>
                    <gndrAgeDesc>ADULT UNISEX</gndrAgeDesc>
                    <gndrAgeNm>01</gndrAgeNm>
                    <prodCd>169831A</prodCd>
                    <prodClsfnDtl>
                        <cmpndTypeNm>IND</cmpndTypeNm>
                        <imprtCtryCd>EU</imprtCtryCd>
                        <prodClsfnItm>
                            <lastUpdatedDate>2020-05-13T12:15:32.102-07:00</lastUpdatedDate>
                            <primFlag>Y</primFlag>
                            <prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                                <fromPrc>0</fromPrc>
                                <fromSz>0C</fromSz>
                                <hts>64039111111</hts>
                                <prcDirection>UP</prcDirection>
                                <szDirection>ABOVE</szDirection>
                            </prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                            <valPctg>100</valPctg>
                            <valTypeNm>BY PERCENTAGE</valTypeNm>
                        </prodClsfnItm>
                        <prodTypeNm>Inline</prodTypeNm>
                    </prodClsfnDtl>
                    <prodPoDtl>
                        <originCountries>US</originCountries>
                        <uom>PR</uom>
                    </prodPoDtl>
                    <seasonNm>Season 2020</seasonNm>
                    <silDesc>Sil description</silDesc>
                    <silNm>020</silNm>
                    <sportActyDesc>Football</sportActyDesc>
                    <sportActyNm>04</sportActyNm>
                </prodCstmsHdr>
                <prodCstmsHdr>
                    <brand>Brand 1</brand>
                    <company>Company name</company>
                    <divNm>20</divNm>
                    <divisionDescription>FOOTWEAR</divisionDescription>
                    <gndrAgeDesc>WOMENS</gndrAgeDesc>
                    <gndrAgeNm>22</gndrAgeNm>
                    <prodCd>5700123</prodCd>
                    <prodClsfnDtl>
                        <cmpndTypeNm>INDIVIDUAL</cmpndTypeNm>
                        <imprtCtryCd>EU</imprtCtryCd>
                        <prodClsfnItm>
                            <itmTypeNm>SHOE</itmTypeNm>
                            <lastUpdatedDate>2020-05-07T12:03:38.933-07:00</lastUpdatedDate>
                            <primFlag>Y</primFlag>
                            <prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                                <fromPrc>0</fromPrc>
                                <fromSz>0C</fromSz>
                                <hts>64041111000</hts>
                                <htsDesc>OTHER</htsDesc>
                                <prcDirection>UP</prcDirection>
                                <szDirection>ABOVE</szDirection>
                            </prodClsfnHTSGrp>
                            <prodMatlCntnt>
                                <athleticFootwear>N</athleticFootwear>
                                <constrCharacteristicDesc>Lined</constrCharacteristicDesc>
                                <constrProcessDesc>V</constrProcessDesc>
                                <coversAnkle>Y</coversAnkle>
                                <factoryCode>9K</factoryCode>
                                <fastenerTypeDesc>Lacing</fastenerTypeDesc>
                                <heelStrapFlag>N</heelStrapFlag>
                                <liningPrimary>
                                    <fiber1>Cotton</fiber1>
                                    <fiber1Percent>100</fiber1Percent>
                                    <material>Textile</material>
                                </liningPrimary>
                                <liningSecondary>
                                    <fiber1>Synthetic Leather</fiber1>
                                    <material>Synthetic</material>
                                </liningSecondary>
                                <measurementSummary>
                                    <coatedLeatherPct>0.0</coatedLeatherPct>
                                    <leatherPct>0.0</leatherPct>
                                    <otherPct>0.0</otherPct>
                                    <summMethodCd>A</summMethodCd>
                                    <syntheticPct>0.0</syntheticPct>
                                    <textilePct>100.0</textilePct>
                                </measurementSummary>
                                <midsole>
                                    <primaryMaterial>EVA</primaryMaterial>
                                </midsole>
                                <onePieceFtw>N</onePieceFtw>
                                <onePieceSole>N</onePieceSole>
                                <openHeelFlag>N</openHeelFlag>
                                <openToeFlag>N</openToeFlag>
                                <outsole>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Rubber</primaryMaterial>
                                    <primaryMaterialPercent>100</primaryMaterialPercent>
                                </outsole>
                                <plugsBottom>N</plugsBottom>
                                <plugsSide>N</plugsSide>
                                <primTechFeatureDesc>Low Density Polymer</primTechFeatureDesc>
                                <sockliner>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Textile</primaryMaterial>
                                </sockliner>
                                <uprLthrNm/>
                                <uprMajority>Textile</uprMajority>
                                <uprOther/>
                                <uprSynthetic/>
                                <uprTextile>
                                    <primaryMaterial>Polyester</primaryMaterial>
                                    <primaryMaterialPercent>100</primaryMaterialPercent>
                                </uprTextile>
                            </prodMatlCntnt>
                            <valPctg>100</valPctg>
                            <valTypeNm>BY PERCENTAGE</valTypeNm>
                        </prodClsfnItm>
                        <prodTypeNm>Inline</prodTypeNm>
                    </prodClsfnDtl>
                    <prodPoDtl>
                        <originCountries>VN</originCountries>
                        <uom>PR</uom>
                    </prodPoDtl>
                    <seasonNm>Season 2020</seasonNm>
                    <silDesc>Sil description</silDesc>
                    <silNm>020</silNm>
                    <sportActyDesc>CASUAL/LEISURE</sportActyDesc>
                    <sportActyNm>29</sportActyNm>
                </prodCstmsHdr>
        </ns2:getProductClassificationUpdatesResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>') xmldoc;
```